# Is it semantically incorrect to put a <div> or <span> inside of a <button>?

Tags: html

I'd like to do the following, but is it semantically correct?

```
<button>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</button>
```

Comment: To clarify this, the question title asks for div or span, the example has just div. So the answers below say div is incorrect, but span is correct.

Answer (score 74):

The current HTML5 draft says it is incorrect.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element says that a `<button>` must contain only Phrasing content. Phrasing content is defined as including `<span>` but not `<div>`.

Comment: Link is OK, but it is reporting ng-click (angular event) as error.

Comment: Prepend 'data-' for 'data-ng-click' so it will validate and still work with AngularJS.

Comment: how come material design uses divs inside their buttons?

Answer (score 42):

`<span>` is valid, `<div>` is not valid. You can verify it at W3C.

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Paste this in the direct input and then validate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<button>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</button>
```

[image]

-- or --

```
<button>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</button>
```

[image]

Set the UTF8 encoding and select HTML5 when testing at W3C.

Comment: Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: Div is considered as an error, span is accepted by https://validator.w3.org

Comment: This is about divs. They are asking about divs or spans.

Comment: @Lisa this question is almost 11yrs old. I could be wrong, but the original question probably wasn't asking about `<span`>. Either way. My answer was simply stating that HTML can be validated at w3 using the validator tool.  I will update my answer to include span, to prevent further confusion.

Answer (score 28):

I'm sure this is heretical, but if you wanted to validate you could always use `<span>` elements inside your button and style them like a `<div>`:

```css
button span {

  display: block;

}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>I'm a div</span>
  <span>I'm a div</span>
  <span>I'm a div</span>
</button>
```

This validated today. Whether it will validate in ten years is another story...

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Div and span elements do not have any semantics. They are *generic* block and inline elements. The only question you need to ask yourself about semantics when you are using them is *Is there an element with better semantics for this content?*.

That said, it is incorrect to place a div inside a button for reasons unrelated to semantics. The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) says about the content model for buttons:

> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

… a span is phrasing content but a div is not.

Answer (score 4):

Span seems legit.

[image]

(screenshot from https://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 2):

2022: No it's not valid.

Buttons can only contain 'Phrasing Content' which does not include divs.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element