# Aligning complex bootstrap button layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got this (not soooo) complex bootstrap button layout that I would like to align right.Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

I would like the second line (Scheduled time) to align right.
I have tried so far all combinations of pull-right and text-right classes on all span tags to no avail...

Anyone has a solution for this?
Thanks!

The button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-pencil fw"></span> &nbsp;
    <asp:literal runat="server" text="&nbsp;<%$ Resources:Main, EstimatedTimeCaption %>" />
    <span data-bind="text: moment(waitingQueueClient.EstimatedConsultationTime).format($('#TimeFormat').html().trim())"></span>
    <br />
    <asp:literal runat="server" text="&nbsp;<%$ Resources:Main, ScheduledTimeCaption %>" />
    <span data-bind="text: moment(waitingQueueClient.FixedConsultationDateTime).format($('#TimeFormat').html().trim())"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Could you use a table?

Comment: Show rendered HTML for CSS questions, please.

Comment: Float the icon and put padding on the text spans instead of aligning to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text-right` utility class Bootstrap provides would make this simple, but the button classes override it. We'll need to be more forceful:

```
.btn.text-right {text-align: right !important;}

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default text-right">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil fw"></span> &nbsp;
    Estimated Time:
    <span>1:41 pm</span><br />
    Scheduled Time: 
    <span>9:30 am</span>
</button>
```

**[Demo](http://liveweave.com/PYigYR)**

Note that I've moved the break tag to the same line as the preceding span. Placing it below adds whitespace at the end of the first line.

Comment: Best answer because it doesn't seem to go against any rules such as div with span. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the break and replaced it with a span with `display:block` and the `text-right` class.

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> &nbsp;
    <span>Caption1</span>
    <span data-bind="...">Time1</span>
    <span style="display:block;" class="text-right">
        <span>Caption2</span>
        <span data-bind="...">Time2</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: It's invalid HTML to place a block-level element in a button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982269/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-put-a-div-or-span-inside-of-a-button

Comment: @Shoe thanks! the thing is that the .net IDE gives an error for <div> within a span as isherwood mentioned. But this still works...