# How to change CSS properties in Meteor Templates?

Tags: javascript, css, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have been trying to fix this problem for days without finding a solution. I am working on a web application that aims at retrieving information from a db. I am using Meteor and blaze. 
As a matter of fact, i would like to  **change css properties in a template event** wether it deals with the css proporties of the click target element or **any** DOM element in the same template.

Here is my template code tag :

```
<button type="button" class="buttonsValue" value="{{value}}"> 
        <div class="CheckButtonsLed"></div>
</button>
```

Here is my template event code :

```
Template.devicesConfiguration.events({

    'click .buttonsValue':function(e, template){

//works well on the parent of the target of the click event :

    $(e.target.parentElement).css('background-color', 'chartreuse');

//works well on the target of the click event :

    e.target.style.backgroundColor="#ffcccc";

//does the same thing but with a different syntax :

    $(e.currentTarget).css('background-color', '#ffcccc');

// Does not work ...

    var CheckButtonsLed = template.find('.CheckButtonsLed');
    CheckButtonsLed.style.marginLeft = '2 em';
    }
});
```

It seems that it does not like the margin proporties while it works for the background property. my class element is my template devicesConfiguration.

I thought first it was because the target of the margin property is not the target of my click event but i tried to change the margin of the target of the event (.buttonsvalue) without results...

does someone have an idea ? thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12982269/2298362. Check this out !

Comment: Thanks ! indeed. I am going to see if i can change css properties now with this button  : 

    <label class="buttonsValue"> 
     <input type="checkbox">
     <div class="CheckButtonsLed"></div>
    </label>

Comment: Well i don't have errors but the css property does not change : Template.devicesConfiguration.events({
    'click .buttonsValue':function(e, template){ 

          var simpleInput = template.find('#simpleInput');simpleInput.style.padding = '2 em';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it works now. it deals with a matter of syntax :

i wrote

```
simpleInput.style.padding = '2 em';
```

instead of ...

```
simpleInput.style.padding = '2em';
```

to put in a nutshell, to change CSS Property of a DOM element (which is not the target of the event)in a meteor template :

```
Template.devicesConfiguration.events({

    'click .buttonsValue':function(e, template){

        var simpleInput = template.find('#simpleInput');

        simpleInput.style.padding = '2em';

    }

});
```

and don't put a div element in a button tag ...

Bye !

Comment: Great you made it!