# Utilize Background Color

Tags: html, css

I currently have a div located inside of a button which is inside another div, like so:

```css
.div1 {
  color: red;
  background: currentColor;
}

button {
  background: green;
}

.span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <button>
    <span class="span"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

The other problem is I don't want to necessarily choose the colors for both, but make it able that the color can be passed down via inheritance for the span.
Is there any way I can make div 2 the same color as div 1, but keep the button as a different color?

Comment: You forgot the closing tag for the div inside the button, that might be the problem.  Do you have any code that you have written to at least *attempt* to solve the problem?

Comment: Putting a `<div>` inside `<button>` is not a valid html. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982269/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-put-a-div-or-span-inside-of-a-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```css
.div1, .div2 { background-color: tomato }
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <button>
        <div class="div2"></div>
    </button>
</div>
```

But better avoid inserting div into the button

You can also use same class for them like that:
(I added borders/padding so you for visual purpose)

```css
button, div {padding: 10px; border: 2px solid blue;}
.red-bg {background: red;}
```

```html
<div class="red-bg">
  <button>
    <div class="red-bg">123</div>
  </button>
</div>
```