# div not staying inside button

Tags: html, css

I have div inside my button, however, the div doesn't stay inside the button.

Heres the link
https://gph.is/g/aNWBDdP

```css
button {
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div>Edit</div>
  <div>**pencil_icon**</div>
</button>
```

Comment: A block-level element [has no business in a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982269/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-put-a-div-or-span-inside-of-a-button/12982334). What's its purpose here? Use a span instead and set it to `inline-block` if necessary.

Comment: You'll need to demonstrate the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/647tahcf/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811669/div-not-staying-inside-button/57811822#comment102054720_57811669) of [isherwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1264804/isherwood):

> A block-level element [has no business in a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982269/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-put-a-div-or-span-inside-of-a-button/12982334). What's its
>   purpose here? Use a span instead and set it to inline-block if
>   necessary.

Comment: Ohh. gotcha. let me try the span.

Comment: You can still do it.

Comment: Sure, without knowing what the asker is building, perhaps disregard to w3 standards is fine - solving the issue while maintaining standards compliance is probably why this answer has been accepted as the solution - that being said, thanks again to @isherwood, who's comment we felt was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The div is inside the button, you just limited the Button's height. Remove the height and watch the button contain the div.

```css
button {
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div>Edit</div>
  <div>**pencil_icon**</div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
button {
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
<button>
  <div>Edit</div>
  <div>**pencil_icon**</div>
</button>


  </body>
</html>
```