# Javascript find the content of a button (1 content per button)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a button

`<button class="collapsible"></button>`

whose content is

`<div class="content"></div>`

On a single page there might be multiple buttons, but **every button is linked to a single content**, so if there are 7 buttons in a page there are 7 contents too.

The **content might be placed far away from its button**, in fact between them there might be text, images, paragraphs, lists, or even another button, but in this last case the content of the second button is placed after the content of the first one.

So these are the typical cases

• button is simply followed by text

```
The <button class="collapsible">sky</button> is blue.
<div class="content">it is above our heads</div>
```

• button is followed by an image and they are both inside a paragraph

```
<p>I saw a <button class="collapsible">cat</button> like this <img ...></p>
<div class="content">The cat is the most beautiful thing in the universe</div>
```

• buttons is outside a ul list while content is inside it

```
The following is a <button class="collapsible">list</button> structure.
<ul>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item <div class="content">it contains items</div></li>
  <li>third item</li>
</ul>
```

• 2 buttons followed by their contents

```
There are 2 <button class="collapsible">buttons</button> in this <button class="collapsible">line</button> as you can see.
First <div class="content">are clickable things</div> and second <div class="content">is a straight thing</div>
```

---

Initially I was using the following **javascript**

```
( function() {
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
} )();
```

Notice how this variable is defined

`var content = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling`

The `parentElement` was necessary since wordpress usually adds `<p>` tags. But later I found out that in some cases the `<p>` tags were not automatically added, and so I edited the JS `content` variable to be

```
var content = this.nextElementSibling;
if (!content) {
    content = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
}
```

Now I'd like to place images or another button between a certain button and its content, but its difficult to handle all the cases using `if`'s.

Since every button is linked to a unique content, is it possibile to write a JS which given the button number `n` it finds the content number `n`?

I was thinking about defining the variables

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var cont = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
```

(so `coll.length == cont.length`) and then for a given `i` associate `coll[i]` with `cont[i]`. So I edited the definition of `content` to be

```
var content = cont[i];
```

but I found out that this doesn't work since at that point `i` is equal to `coll.length`, that is `i` is out of range. This is the full JS I was thinking about

```
( function() {
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var cont = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = cont[i];
    console.log(content)
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
} )();
```

Comment: not directly related to the question itself, but, about div inside button: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12982269/8732818

Comment: You should try declaring new attributes in html tags and using it to identify the content. Ex: <button class="collapsible" data-content="content-a"></button>

Comment: If you answered your own question post it below and accept it. Don't post the answer within the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work in all cases

```
<script type="text/javascript">
( function() {
    coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    cont = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].setAttribute('data-id', 'con' + i);
        cont[i].setAttribute('id', 'con' + i);
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-id'));
            if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    }
} )();
</script>
```