# How to trigger function only in parent div, not child

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
<button onClick={onClickParent}>
<div className={"iconDiv"}>
<div className={"iconNameDiv"}> 
</button>
```

I have something like this structure.
When I click the button, It will change the color of the button
However, when I click the inside div, this onclick funtion didn't work.
How to prevent onclick inside div ? only parent

Comment: Why are you placing a ```div``` tag inside button?? And what do you mean by parent div and child div here?? There is no enough clarification in question..

Comment: Making a div inside a button is also not a valid one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982269/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-put-a-div-or-span-inside-of-a-button

Comment: because i want to align icon with iconName

Answer (score 2):

Generally whatever is inside a button tag should be used for the button click, so I would go for a `div` tag which can be used for alignment of children. Below is the code for preventing child element triggering clicks, just check the class and ensure that its the same as class of the parent div.

```js
function test(event) {
  if(event.target.className === 'test') {
    console.log('execute click code');
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div onClick="test(event)" class="test">
  <div className="test1"> asdfasdf</div>
  <div className="test2"> asdfasdf</div>
</div>
```