# Weird "div in button" behaviour

Tags: html, css

So i have a button and a div inside. When i press on the div inside button i see white rectangle block on whole width of a button and on a half height of a button. But when i press below or higher that div, button pressed normal
Btw here it works properly:

```css
.form__button__section__button__social__facebook{
    width: 420px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    background: #597DA3;
    background-image: url("facebook_logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 112px center;
}
   .form__button__section__button__social__facebook:focus{
        background-color: #3B5998;
        border: 1px solid rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.1);
        box-sizing: border-box;}
.form__button__section__button__social__facebook:hover,:active{
    background-color: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.1), rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.1)), #3B5998;
}
.buttonInside2{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<button  class="form__button__section__button__social__facebook" name="facebool" ><div class="buttonInside2">Facebook</div></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `<div>` inside a `<button>`. W3 HTML docs says that a `<button>` must contain only phrasing content. Phrasing content is defined as including `<span>` but not `<div>`.

It is also incorrect when validated: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

SOURCE: [Is it semantically incorrect to put a <div> or <span> inside of a <button>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982269/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-put-a-div-or-span-inside-of-a-button)

---

Sidenote: You should also clean up your code. For example `linear-gradient` can't be used as `background-color`, but should be used as `background-image`