# Why my dropdown content does not work on Safari?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I made an dropdown navbar like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>



.dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;  
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width:100px;
 

}
 .dropbtn:hover  {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
  min-width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
 


<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

but when I open this website in Safari on Iphone I cant use the dropdown it doesnt work. However if I make .dropbtn a button instead of div it works but now validator doesnt except button to have div and a as child. How can I change the code to make the website valid and can be used on Safari at the same time?

Comment: Touch devices don't have a hover pseudo state. Some emulate it but it's always buggy and you should assume there is no such thing for better UX.

Answer (score 0):

While buttons cannot have div or anchor elements as children, they can have span elements.

The following snippet passed W3C validation. Is it a hack?

Possibly, given button elements are not supposed to have interactive content descendants. See e.g. [Is it semantically incorrect to put a <div> or <span> inside of a <button>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982269/is-it-semantically-incorrect-to-put-a-div-or-span-inside-of-a-button/12982334) for discussion and references on this.

On the other hand it gets us round a problem on touchscreens with minimal alteration and minimal JS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>



.dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;  
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width:100px;
 

}
 .dropbtn:hover  {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
  min-width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content, button span {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
    <span class="dropdown-content">
      <span onclick="window.location = 'Wherever';">Link 1</span>
      <span onclick="" >Link 2</span>
      <span onclick= "">Link 3</span>
    </span>
    </button>
   <div id='id1'>id1</div>


<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```